# Making a UTF-8 call from VBA

Tags: vba, utf-8

I'm trying to make calls to openstreetmap (specifically to [https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?amenity=charging_station&format=json&q=Elly-Beinhorn-Ring+2,12529+Schönefeld](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?amenity=charging_station&format=json&q=Elly-Beinhorn-Ring+2,12529+Sch%C3%B6nefeld)
) and from any webbrowser it works fine. When calling via Excel VBA is complains that the string is not UTF-8. I haven't used fiddler yet but to me it is clear that srequest should be in UTF-8 format. I found another solution to convert the url to ascii but I'd prefer to have it in utf-8 here's some sample code which creates the error:

```
 Dim httpObject As Object
 Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
 srequest = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?amenity=charging_station&format=json&q=Elly-Beinhorn-Ring+2,12529+Schönefeld"
 httpObject.Open "GET", srequest, False
 httpObject.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
 httpObject.send
 sgetResult = httpObject.responsetext

 Debug.Print sgetResult
```

If anybody can help how to force MSXML2 to make an utf-8 call, i'd be happy. at the moment my solution is to replace German Umlauts (ä,ü,ö) with (ae,ue,oe) which works but is not what I want. Other solutions like URLEncode() have created more chaos by also converting + and , to values starting with %.

Comment: If you only need to use the webservice when workbook data is refreshed, consider using [Power Query](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/03/26/working-with-web-services-in-power-query/).

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your hint. I have a bunch of individual adresses I want to geo-code. From my understanding Powerquery isnt't meant for this scenario.

Comment: You could ask as a different question. But in brief, you can easily convert between tables, lists and structured text, including JSON and XML. Menus and dialogs can insert or edit transformation steps or you can write all or some of the code yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve my problem by replacing this line:

```
 Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
```

with this one:

```
Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
```

Comment: thanks! I tried some code for converting the URL itself but this solution is the most easiest one indeed and working like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Forcing MSXML2 to utf-8 is not the right way to go. All browsers convert to ASCII before sending the request. Easiest way to see this is in the Network tab in your browser Dev tools. Chrome translates your URL to

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?amenity=charging_station&format=json&q=Elly-Beinhorn-Ring+2,12529+Sch%C3%B6nefeld
```

So the easy way is to encode ö to %C3%B6 (as described here: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f6/index.htm) and the other characters in a similar way. There are a lot of encoding methods available out there. Have a look

Comment: hi Sam, thanks for your answer, but you're partially right. Firefox does not convert to ASCII, Edge may convert but actually fails to show what it does in the Developer console (which pretty much sums up the whole issue I guess).