# VB macro changing encoding on REST request

Tags: vba, encoding

I have an excel file with a button associated to a VB macro like this:

```
Sub button_macro()
    Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    MyRequest.Open "GET", "http://theurl/service?param=""Gestión"""
    MyRequest.Send
End Sub
```

But the response I get is something like:

```
"GestiÃ³n" is not a valid value for param.
```

How can I avoid VB converting the 'ó' character to another encoding?

If I send the request via browser like:

```
http://theurl/service?param="Gestión"
```

The service answer as desired.

EDIT:

Curiously `MsgBox "Código único"` works as expected showing the 'ó' and 'ú' characters correctly.

Comment: Does it work without the quotes?  I've never seen quoted querystring parameters...

Comment: The real use case contains several words for param, like "Gestión CAR", so I must enclose them in double quotes (the service doesn't work other way).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182394/making-a-utf-8-call-from-vba and maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba (you likely need the UTF-supporting one from the accepted answer)

Comment: FYI it works in the browser because the browser encodes the request for you - you can see that if you use your browser's Developer tools - eg for your "example" URL of `http://theurl/service?param="Gestión"` I see `http://theurl/service?param=%22Gesti%C3%B3n%22`

Comment: I see, using "Gesti%C3%B3n" works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Please, try something like this: `myRequest.Open "GET", "http://theurl/service?param=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL("""Gestión""")`. It should work with any string containing characters necessary to be encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in the browser because the browser encodes the request for you - you can see that if you use your browser's Developer tools - eg for your "example" URL of

```
http://theurl/service?param="Gestión"
```

I see

```
http://theurl/service?param=%22Gesti%C3%B3n%22
```

You can encode your parameters using (eg) the UTF-supporting method from the accepted answer here: [How can I URL encode a string in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba)